# Force HTTP AUTH over HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-authentication

I have a directory of my website I would like to secure. I am doing this using a .htaccess file to force a HTTP AUTH. I would like to force this HTTP AUTH to be done over HTTPS.

Looking at various solutions on stack overflow here is the point I have got to:

I have the following .htaccess file in the 'top_secret' directory:

```
SSLRequireSSL
ErrorDocument 403 /rd.php
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Secure Page"
AuthUserFile "/home/usr/.htpasswds/public_html/top_secret/passwd"
Require valid-user
```

I then have 'rd.php' in my root directory:

```
<?php
$path = "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80) {
    header("Status: 302 Moved\n");
    header("Location: ".$path."\n\n");
}
else {
    header( "Content-type: text/html\n\n");
    echo '?';
}
?>
```

This works quite well on my desktop computer, however when I browse to the top_secret directory from my iphone in safari (to the HTTPS or HTTP address) I just get a question mark returned. So for some reason the else condition of my php file is being outputted.

I am not exactly sure what this means and how to resolve, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I already answered your question. If you're not happy with my answer could you tell me why and I'll update it or address your concerns? Thanks.

Comment: Are you just going to waste your bounty? I am offering to update my answer for you, but can't do that without some feedback from you.

Comment: Assume that safari browser get 403 from the `Require` directive via HTTPS due to incorrect behavior with `AuthType Basic`.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than do this in PHP, I suggest you implement it on the web server layer. Add this to the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

And remove your PHP redirect code.

But this is still going to require log-in before the redirect is issued, with the details being transferred insecurely. What you really need is two `<VirtualHost>` blocks in Apache. One for port 80 that redirects requests for your directory to HTTPS, and one for port 443 that has the HTTP AUTH configured.

**Update**

Also it makes no sense to try and issue a 302 redirect within a document that is used as the 403 error document, since the status code has already been set and the document is only being used to generate the body of that response, so it can't now change the response code to 302 because it has already been set to 403. The approach I've outlined above will work, or you could simply deny HTTP requests and serve HTTPS only for that directory.

Comment: Hi SuperDuperApps, many apologises for my late reply and thank you kindly for your assistance on this issue. This is a good option, but as you say it requires 2x authentications with one sent in the clear (which I would like to avoid). Further, when I run this I get a code 500 server error. Is there any chance you could point me toward further documentation detailing how I would setup virtualhosts as you describe?

Comment: For the 500 internal server error, check your error logs to see what the problem is. For setting up virtual hosts in Apache, there is [documentation here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/). It depends on your setup how you need to do it. If you have any problems then you could open a new question and post some of your config.

Answer (score 1):

If you're behind beanstalk or any loadbalancer then you can set redirect  on that level. Otherwise write .htaccess config suggested by @SuperDuperApps. This should be a comment but I don't have enough rep ;-)

Comment: you should probably just write this as a comment below the post to which you are referring.

Comment: I was just trying to help, I don't have reputation to comment, why you down vote? I haven't said anything wrong? I wasted time to answer you? You?

Comment: ah, didn't see that you don't have enough reputation to comment - good point and if you edit your post i'll remove the downvote:)

Comment: Now you nearly have enough rep :-) I upvoted this and @JohnGallagher I edited the post so perhaps you can do that now.